# Synonym for a very insignificant product improvement

Tags: synonyms

How would you call a very insignificant product improvement? Think in the context of a company that creates a very careless add-on to a last-year product just to claim that now the product is new and improved when in fact the improvement has no added value?

My take, which is way too wordy: a cosmetic afterthought with little purpose.

Any shorter version?

Comment: Well, in most cases it's just "New!" or "Improved!" or "Advanced!" or some such.  (The exclamation point is mandatory.)

Comment: Useless variant, non functional.

Comment: Are you familiar with SFTR?  Its what you call this when the govt issues a procurement request for an updated replacement. In one howler, the government bought a Specific Force Integrating Resolver, which was widely believed to be a backronym of *same frigging instrument, renamed*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single word for this escapes me, but there are many options if you simply find synonyms for *insignificant* and *improvement* that imply value specifically.

> [**trivial**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/trivial) (adj.)
> Of little value or importance
> *"That is a trivial addition."*
>
> [**negligible**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/negligible) (adj.)
> So small or unimportant as to be not worth considering; insignificant
> *"That is a negligible add-on."*
>
> [**paltry**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/paltry) (adj.)
> Petty; trivial
> *"That is a paltry variant."*

I personally feel that *trivial* is your best bet because it can imply value specifically, but any of these could work.

Answer (score 2):

[**gimmick**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gimmick)

> a method or trick that is used to get people's attention or to sell something

Here's a good example of the word used in this way:

> Americans have made it clear: They don’t want a lot of gimmicks in their TVs.
>
> In an effort to improve sales, though, television makers have tried gimmicks anyway. They have praised 3-D TVs. They have promoted voice controls. And they have highlighted Internet-streaming interfaces. [NYT](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/10/09/technology/personaltech/sharper-image-4k-tv-gimmick-worth-having.html)

Comment: _Gimmick_ would make the insignificant improvement a trick instead of a simple pointless addition.

Answer (score 2):

Marginal meets the requirements of your original question.

Marginal: at the outer or lower limits; minimal for requirements; almost insufficient: marginal subsistence; marginal ability.

Usage example:

The Marvelous Margin Maker showed marginal improvements in 2016.

Answer (score 1):

**superficial** /ˌso͞opərˈfiSHəl/ adjective

> appearing to be true or real only until examined more closely.
>   not thorough, deep, or complete; cursory. –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=superficial%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

The *superficial* difference between a Bentley and a Rolls-Royce is the addition of a superfluous nameplate.

---

**superfluous** /so͞oˈpərflo͞oəs/ adjective

> unnecessary, especially through being more than enough. –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=surpurfouils&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=superfluous%20definition)

I think that 'superficial' nails it on the head, so this may have been a *superfluous* edit (but it was the first word that came to mind).

Answer (score 1):

Your [title] header says “insignificant,” but your [question’s] body says “**no** added value.”
 To the extent that it’s true that “no means no,” I’d go with:
 [“worthless addition.”](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/114533-fire-emblem-fates-conquest/73520439?jumpto=30)
(seemingly relevant use from *gamefaqs[dot]com*)

If insignificant means insignificant, by using [*Dictionary[dot]com’s* fifth meaning](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/insignificant) for that adjective (without meaning; meaningless) you could go with:
[“meaningless addition.”](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/36663010)
(seemingly relevant use from *dpreview[dot]com*)

Returning to [“worthless addition”](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mantissa) in closing (cf: *etymonline[dot]com*),  for a single word you could consider:
 [“makeweight’](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/makeweight), which *Merriam-Webster* defines as a noun meaning:
 “b :  something of little independent value thrown in to fill a gap,”
or else go with the obsolete meaning of
 [“mantissa’](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mantissa):
 “2. 
Obsolete: an addition of little or no importance, as to a literary work”
(from *Dictionary[dot]com*)